# how to edit menu bar in active admin? - change the language. Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin

I'm using Active Admin with i18n. Everything works but if i want to change language I need to do that by hand - changing site address :-(... How to add buttons in navigate bar with models names? It could be another place but good for that - accessible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set a default locale in a before filter by adding the following lines to application_controller.rb:

```
before_filter :set_locale

def set_locale
  I18n.locale = params[:locale] || I18n.default_locale
end

def default_url_options(options={})
  { :locale => I18n.locale }
end
```

Add a menu for selecting languages in active_admin.rb:

```
config.namespace :admin do |admin|
  admin.build_menu :utility_navigation do |menu|
    menu.add :label => "Languages" do |lang|
      lang.add :label => "English",:url => proc { url_for(:locale => 'en') }, id: 'i18n-en', :priority => 1
      lang.add :label => "Mexican",:url => proc { url_for(:locale => 'es') }, id: 'i18n-es', :priority => 2
    end
    menu.add :label => proc { display_name current_active_admin_user },
              :url => '#',
              :id => 'current_user',
              :if => proc { current_active_admin_user? }
    admin.add_logout_button_to_menu menu
  end
end
```

You can set the default locale in application.rb:

```
config.before_configuration do
  I18n.load_path += Dir[Rails.root.join('config', 'locales', '*.{rb,yml}').to_s]
  I18n.default_locale = :en
  I18n.reload!
end
```